# How to receive Metadata from MP3 Streaming URL (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I build a radio Player app for a specific radio station. All is working fine but I want to show the current title In an UILabel. How do I do this? 
URL of the Stream: http://streams.rsh.de/rsh-live/mp3-192/mediaplayer

In iTunes the metadata show correctly.